# Volley inserta datos vacios

Tags: android, kotlin, volley

Es la primera vez que hago una conexión a un webservice, o eso intento, instale postman e inserta correctamente los datos en la base de datos pero al momento de enviar la solicitud desde mi dispositivo Android hace la inserción pero todos los campos están vacíos, no se que estoy haciendo mal

Mi Activity es esta

```
class RegisterActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private val URL_REGIST:String="http://192.168.100.8:8888/Registro/prueba.php"

lateinit var name:EditText
lateinit var email:EditText
lateinit var pass:EditText
lateinit var button:Button

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register)

    name = findViewById(R.id.name)
    email = findViewById(R.id.email)
    pass = findViewById(R.id.pass)

    button = findViewById(R.id.button)

    val jsonobj= JSONObject()

    button.setOnClickListener {
            jsonobj.put("name", name.text)
            jsonobj.put("email", email.text)
            jsonobj.put("pass", pass.text)

        val que = Volley.newRequestQueue(this@RegisterActivity)
        val req = JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,URL_REGIST,jsonobj,
            Response.Listener {
                    response ->
                println("registrado")
            }, Response.ErrorListener {
                println("Error")
            }
        )

        que.add(req)
    }

}
```

}

Y mi archivo php es este

```
<?php
$user_name_in_php = $_GET["name"];
$user_email_in_php = $_GET["email"];
$password_in_php = $_GET["pass"];
$db_username = "root";
$db_password = "";
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_name = "androidprueba";
$con = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name);
$sql = "insert into user_table(name, email, pass) values('".$user_name_in_php."','".$user_email_in_php."','".$password_in_php."');";
if(mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{

    $result["success"] = "1";
    $result["message"] = "Data insertion success";

        echo json_encode($result);
}
else
{

    $result["success"] = "0";
    $result["message"] = "Data insertion failed";

        echo json_encode($result);
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

En Potman funciona
[image: prueba en Postman]

intente cambiar por método POST pero me marcaba este error en postman

```
<b>Notice</b>: Undefined index: name in <b>C:\laragon\www\Registro\prueba.php</b> on line <b>2</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>: Undefined index: email in <b>C:\laragon\www\Registro\prueba.php</b> on line <b>3</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>: Undefined index: pass in <b>C:\laragon\www\Registro\prueba.php</b> on line <b>4</b><br />
```

En la Actividad puse este codigo para intentar ver el error pero no se si es la forma correcta

```
Response.ErrorListener {error ->
                println("Error"+error+jsonobj)
```

e imprime esto

```
2019-12-31 17:43:10.124 1973-1973/com.ange1d.loginwithvolley I/System.out: Errorcom.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject{"name":"angel","email":"angel@mail.com","pass":"12345"}
```

tambien intente enviando un null en vez de mi variable JSONObject e imprime lo mismo asi que no entiendo cual es el problema

edit: **La solucion es:**

para el método GET insertar los valores en la url

```
private val URL_REGIST:String="http://192.168.100.8:8888/Registro/prueba.php?name=angel&email=angel@email.com&pass=123456"


val req = JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,URL_REGIST,null,
```

para el método POST es modificar el archivo php como en esta 
[pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45865519/post-in-php-not-populated-using-volley-library-jsonobjectrequest-method-post)

Comment: no le estas pasando el jsonobj al crear el JsonObjectRequest, por eso no te llegan los parametros

Comment: @ErickSilva le envio el jsonobj
val req = JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,URL_REGIST,jsonobj,

pero marca el mismo error, de hecho le puse null para ver si mostraba un error diferente

Comment: También cambie el método JsonObjectRequest por stringRequest
y en este caso no marca error 
2020-01-02 10:01:50.552 7974-7974/com.ange1d.loginwithvolley I/System.out: registrado

pero tampoco inserta la información solo ingresa campos vacíos

Comment: oh, ok. Los parametros solos los toma en cuenta en caso de ser POST o PUT, el request no lleva parametros en el body porque los GET no tienen body. Agrega los parametros en la url tal como lo estas armando en postman y te va a funcionar.

Comment: @ErickSilva Gracias, ya inserta los datos, solo una pregunta mas 

Si quiero usar el método POST con JsonObjectRequest debo agregar algo mas?
cambie las variables en php de $_GET["name"] a $_POST["name"] y el metodo a POST en StringRequest y también lo inserta pero en JsonObjectRequest sigue marcando error `String cannot be converted to JSONObject`

Comment: Desde Android tal como esta el codigo solo deberias cambiar GET por POST en php supongo que tenes que cambiar la forma en que recibis los parametros, pero no se mucho de php, googlea algun ejemplo, seguro que hay muchisimos